# CakePHP method to remove all relationships in a join table

Tags: php, cakephp

In my app I have a system of Posts and Topics and attaching Topics to Posts using a join table called Topic_Post. To make sure that when a user edits or removes topics for the post  is efficient and clean I want to remove all relationships BEFORE I re-add or add new ones in. **NOTE: I mean attach or detach them from the Post and NOT actually deleting the Topic**

What is the best way of doing this? I'd need to pass the post id to the method and then find all the records in the Topic Post table that have a matching post_id and then remove those records from the table.

These are the associations:

```
Post.php
class Post extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Post';

    public $belongsTo = 'User';

    public $hasMany = array('Answer');

    // Has many topics that belong to topic post join table... jazz
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Topic' => array('with' => 'TopicPost')
    );
}

Topic.php
class Topic extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'TopicPost'
    );
}

TopicPost.php
class TopicPost extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Topic', 'Post'
    );
}
```

In the Topiic_Post table I have made the two foreign keys unique to prevent duplication.

`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_row` (`topic_id`,`post_id`)

And the method is like this so far:

```
function cleanPostTopics ($postId) {

$post = $this->find('first', 'condition'=>array('Post.id'=>$postId));

}
```

How would I then use this `$post` to find all the records in the TopicPost table and then delete them! Remember to acknowledge that this method is inside one of the models and needs to be able to talk to the others based on my associations.

It's worth noting that I insert/attach Topics using the following method if that breaks any of the inbuilt CakePHP logic that apparently should of been prevent duplications from happening? http://pastebin.com/d2Kt8D2R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake handles this automatically for you. When you delete a Post or Topic, it should remove all HABTM associated data.

For hasOne and hasMany relationships, you can define `'dependent' => true` in your relationship to have that associated data removed when the record is deleted.

```
// When a Post is deleted, the associated Answer records will be as well
public $hasMany = array(
  'Answer' => array(
    'dependent' => true
  )
);
```

You can read more info on it here:

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html

Based on your setup, you can delete related HABTM data like so:

```
function cleanPostTopics ($postId) {

  $post = $this->find('first', 'condition'=>array('Post.id'=>$postId));
  // find all HABTM with that post id
  $topicsPost = $this->TopicPost->deleteAll(array(
      'TopicsPost.post_id' => $postId
  ), false);

}
```

Comment: Yeah but I'm **NOT** deleting the Post or the Topic! This method will be run before the save of a post to clean up relationships! (I have my reasons for doing this as outlined in the OP)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that in the question. It's worth noting that when you add new HABTM data, the original is completely cleared out beforehand to prevent duplicates, if that was your concern.

Comment: For me it's not cleared out. It duplicates the records and to prevent this I have created made the foreign keys unique to force unique records but this will cause an error as CakePHP will still try and insert them into the table hence what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That's interesting, and not the correct behavior as stated in the docs and from everything I've seen.

Comment: Well unless you can see something wrong with my associations above? It's worth noting that I insert/attach the topics using the following code: http://pastebin.com/d2Kt8D2R so perhaps that is bypassing/breaking the behaviour and if so how can I prevent it?

Comment: Yes, it's bypassing. See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm for info about saving HABTM. If you use `saveAll` with with a `Post` and `TopicPost => TopicPost => array(1,2,3)` sort of array, it will be taken care of automatically.

Comment: Also, check out this blog post: http://marianoiglesias.com.ar/cakephp/something-to-consider-when-saving-habtm-records-in-cakephp/

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. Where should I be using the saveAll method?

Comment: Well the method goes inside the Topic.php model as it talks to the TopicPost model via a belongsTo association but there is no direct link to the post model so that saveAll on the return causes an error and changing it to TopicPost like in the original or removing the model name from the method doesn't save the TopicPost data JUST the Topics only! Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: `$this->TopicPost->Post->saveAll(...);` ?

Comment: Nope still not saving to the TopicPost table :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10291/discussion-between-jeremyharris-and-cameron)